# Why can't I concatenate patterns evaluated at compile and run-time under qr?

Tags: regex, perl

Why does this bomb

```
perl -e 'print qr{$_(??{$_})}'
```

while both of these work separately:

```
perl -e 'print qr{$_}'
perl -e 'print qr{(??{$_})}'
```

The error message is

```
Eval-group not allowed at runtime, use re 'eval' in regex m/(??{$_})/ at -e line 1.
```

Really, should I upgrade Perl? I have 5.14.4.

Comment: works here, v5.18.1.  time to upgrade?

Comment: What's the bomb? A descriptive error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in [`5.18.0`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/perl-5.18.1/pod/perl5180delta.pod#Selected_Bug_Fixes) and `5.17.1`.

> The implementation of code blocks in regular expressions, such as (?{}) and (??{}), has been heavily reworked to eliminate a whole slew of bugs. The main user-visible changes are:
>
> - Code blocks within patterns are now parsed in the same pass as the surrounding code;
> - Lexical variables are now sane as regards scope, recursion and closure behavior.